# error: package aurelienribon.tweenengine does not exist

Tags: android, libgdx

I set up the Project with LibGDX gradle and everything worked fine until i addet  Tween Engine Library to our libGDX projects

my project convert from eclipse to android studio.

My build.gradle looks like this :

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.kilobolt.zombiebird.android/com.kilobolt.zombiebird.android.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/tween-engine-api.jar')
    compile files('libs/tween-engine-api-sources.jar')
}
```

error :

```
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.Tween;// error: package aurelienribon.tweenengine does not exist
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenEquations;//error: package aurelienribon.tweenengine does not exist
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager;//error: package aurelienribon.tweenengine does not exist
```

I really don't know what to do, i cant understand why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried re-running gradle build from the command line first?

Answer (score 4):

For context, this question appears to reference the [LibGDX Zombie Bird Tutorial - Day 11](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-11-supporting-iosandroid--splashscreen-menus-and-tweening.html).

Resolve the dependency error by following the [Universal Tween Engine FileTree Dependency Method](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine) instructions.

The instructions say:

> the project(":core") section of your build.gradle file should now look
>   like this:

```
project(":core") {
   ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

> the project(":android") section of your build.gradle file should now
>   look like this:

```
project(":android") {
   ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}
```

After following those instructions, modify the directory path to '../libs/tween-engine-api-6.3.3' or whatever your folder for the Universal Tween Engine is named. Remember to re-sync your project with the build.gradle updates you just made.

My complete build.gradle for this project is shown below. However, my project was originally generated using the LibGDX Setup App and was not imported from Eclipse.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.12.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "ZombieBird"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.2'
        roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs/tween-engine-api-6.3.3', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs/tween-engine-api-6.3.3', include: '*.jar');
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace it with

```
compile "org.mini2Dx:universal-tween-engine:6.3.3"
```

in the file `build.gradle` of the root project.